# Devise - NoMethodError in Registrations#new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nomethoderror

Everything worked fine on my development machine (windows xp, ROR 3.0.3, SQLite3).

When I moved the application to the production server (FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE, Apache 2.2, ROR 3.0.4, MySQL), this error appeared, but only on new registration page.

When I try to login (there are no users in the database), password check seems to work (it says that password incorrect, which is fine).

The problem occurs only on the production server, no problem on the developement server. What could it be?

Thanks!

[edit] added 09.08.2011:

routes.rb:

```
  #USERS
  get "/user/stat"
  devise_for :users do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
  get "/users" => "user#index"
  resources :user
```

registations_controller.rb:

```
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    render_with_scope :new
  end

  protected

    # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
    # temporary session data to the newly created user.
    def build_resource(hash=nil)
      hash ||= params[resource_name] || {}
      self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash, session)
    end
```

log/production.log:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 192.168.5.7 at 2011-08-09 13:40:31 +0400
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  SQL (31.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
Completed   in 33ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `new_with_session' for #<Class:0x284ac6a8>):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:71:in `build_resource'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:8:in `new'
```

Comment: Can you post some code? (registrations_controller, routes.rb, and other devise-related stuff)

Comment: Update: the problem disappeared, I don't remember how and why. But this time it reappeared again, and I also don't understand why and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the owner of the app directory to the same user as HTTPD process owner:

```
$ chown -R <username> <your_app_dir>
```

e.g.

```
$ chown -R www /usr/local/www/apache22/data
```

and update Devise:

```
$ bundle update
```

Gemfile specifies the latest Devise version:

```
gem 'devise'
```

That worked for me.